# Posso perguntar sobre Ciências Sociais e Humanas?

Tags: discussion

É adequado fazer perguntas sobre Ciências Sociais e Humanas neste site?
Assim como definidas na Wikipedia?

- [Ciências Sociais](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncias_sociais)

  [Ciências Humanas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ci%C3%AAncias_humanas)

Comment: E a pergunta ficava melhor, mais clara, com exemplos. :)

Comment: Obrigado @ANeves. Eu não conhecia o `meta`. Concordo com você. O Administrador pode mover.

Comment: @FranciscoAloisio o que o ANeves queria dizer, era colocar exemplos dessas perguntas.